# Why does OneDrive js picker sometimes have null opener

Tags: javascript, iframe, onedrive

I am trying to integrate the OneDrive picker with our web application and after reading [Nick's answer to this question on 10/02/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400180/support-for-multiple-domains-subdomains-in-onedrive-file-picker-for-web-apps/32901833#32901833) have chosen the route of using an iframe and utilizing postMessage. So after inserting the iframe with a button to open the OneDrive Picker and selecting a file, the popup window persists with just a spinner icon and there is an error in the console `r is null`. I know that, given [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434283/one-drive-js-file-picker-error-in-windows-opener) having a form can cause this issue and I removed the form in the page loaded in the iframe but still see the error where `window.opener == null` (see screenshot below). Has anybody else seen this before? I had a theory that the query parameters in the URL was the cause but removing those didn't appear to resolve the issue.

*Debugging onedrive.js when error occurs (and popup window persists after selecting a file)*:
[image: Error where opener is null]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the cause was that the iframe was being loaded in a "popover" - a div with absolute positioning that appears when a link is clicked and then disappears after the interaction is over. And when the containing div is hidden, it is causing the iframe to reload - you should try a technique descibed [here](https://medium.com/@jakob/change-an-iframe-parent-without-reload-3563d79d50a9#.ba96sy998)